# Determine the asymptotic complexity

Tags: math, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

If I'm given two functions and asked to find asymptotic complexity for both, what does that mean? Is it O() or Big Theta? For example
f1(n)=a^n and 
f2(n)=n^3+n^2

Should I say that f1 is O(a^n) and f2 is O(n^3) or should I use big-theta?

Comment: Asymptotic complexity includes both. Which one whomever asked you the question wanted you to pick is anyone's guess. From the asker's point of view, Big-Theta would be better, as it specifies a lower and upper bound, preventing you from just (correctly) saying both are `O(n^n)` (assuming `a` is a constant).

Comment: For a function like f(n)=log(n^0.3), wouldn't it be O(log n) and Big-theta(log n).

Answer (score 2):

O notation provides an asymptotic upper bound; if f(n) = O(g(n)), it intuitively means that f grows no faster than g.

Θ notation, on the other hand, specifies a tight bound.  If f(n) = Θ(g(n)), it means f and g grow at the same rate, up to some constant factor.  Technically speaking, f(n) = Θ(n) implies that f(n) = O(g(n)), though the reverse isn't always true.

The most precise analysis you can give would be to use Θ notation, though it would not be wrong to use O notation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Big Oh and Big Theta are both used in asymptotic analysis.  To say that a function f(n) = O(n^3) means that it grows no faster than n^3.  To say that a function f(n) = Θ(n^3) means that it grows as fast as n^3.